# Elliptic points of Г1

Tags: number-theory

There is an exercise 2.3.7 in Diamond, Shurman "A first course in Modular forms":

Prove that there are no elliptic points for the group $Г_1(N)$, $N>3$.

$Г_1(N)=\begin{pmatrix}
 a& b\\
 c& d\\
\end{pmatrix}$ $\in SL_2(\mathbb{Z})$,
$s.t.\begin{pmatrix}
 a& b\\
 c& d\\
\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}
 1& *\\
 0& 1\\
\end{pmatrix}$ mod N

That is $Г_1(N)=\begin{pmatrix}
 kN+1& *\\
 lN& mN+1\\
\end{pmatrix}$$\in SL_2(\mathbb{Z})$

Could someone help to prove it?

Comment: What have you tried? The goal is to show that $\Gamma_1(N)$ contains no nontrivial elements of order $2,3,4,6$ when $N > 3$. The case $2$ is trivial and the case $4$ follows. For $3$ (which implies $6$), use the characteristic polynomial.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Case 2 ok, about 3 I'll think later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Too long for a comment... Searching in a pedestrian manner for an elliptic point $\tau$ in the upper half plane $\Bbb H$, stabilized by some non-trivial $A$, $A\ne \pm 1$, with entries $a,b,c,d$ we obtain:
$$
\tau=\begin{bmatrix}a & b \\ c& d\end{bmatrix}\cdot \tau =\frac{a\tau + b}{c\tau+d}\ ,
$$
and the obtained equation of second degree in $\tau$ is $0=c\tau^2 - (a-d)\tau -b$. A solution $\tau$,
$$
\tau =\frac 1{2c}(\ (a-d)\pm\sqrt{(a-d)^2+4bc}\ )
$$
lives in $\Bbb H$
iff we have a negative number under the square root. This gives:
$$
(a+d)^2 =((a-d)^2 +4bc) +4(ad-bc) < 0 + 4\ .
$$
So $a+d$ is an integer among $-1,0,1$. But $a+d$ is $2$ modulo $N$, and $N>3$. No chance.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I tried this way, but didnt know what to do with expression under square root. So simple...